# What happens to a person's questions/answers when they delete their account?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

If a person deletes their Stack Overflow account, what will happen to questions and answers posted by them?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing.

They will remain on the site, though without being attached to the name anymore (i.e. - they will be anonymised).

The could still get upvotes and downvotes as usual, though no one would gain or lose reputation from those votes.

Comment: Aha so if the person for instance deleted a question before deleting their account. 10k+ users would see deleted by 'anonymous', pardon me but I am a bit curious...

Comment: @OmarHossamAhmed Generally, when a user is deleted, the username defaults to the userXXXX format... but it's greyed out and not linked to any other content. Example here: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/30319/my-wife-wants-a-homosexual-child So a 10K user in that case would see the same thing, "userXXXX". Generally, if the post is deleted, the username still links to their account page, though.

Comment: @OmarHossamAhmed Please don't delete questions or answers before you delete your account that type of behavior isn't encouraged.  Mass removing content like that will result the content being restored anyways